# Spring MVC @Controller method signatures

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Is there an easy way to view all the possible method signature when I create a controller by annotating a class with `@Controller`?

I can't find a spring documentation that lists all of that. From their guide, it seems to be **really** flexible where I don't know what I can be returning or what I could use in the method parameters.

Comment: Do you have an example ? it's not clear to me what you want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should check the [Spring MVC reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) again. In the "[Defining @RequestMapping handler methods](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods)" chapter, everything is listed and explained :

- [all the possible parameters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments)
- [all the possible return types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types)
- all the possible method/parameter annotations, each one having its sub-chapter : @RequestParam, @RequestBody, @ResponseBody, @ModelAttribute, etc.